# Why does my update in a put request overwrite the whole record in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, request, sequelize.js

I'm trying to make a "edit" feature for my project, and I'm stuck at this part..

I have a put request :

```
export const updateEvent = (event, id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  request
    .put(`${baseUrl}/event/${id}`)
    .send(event)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(updatedEvent(response.body))
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

This is the route for the said put, with Sequelize as ORM:

```
router.put('/event/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  try {
    const event = await Event.findByPk(id)
    const updatedEvent = await event.update(req.body)
    res.send(updatedEvent)
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})
```

When I test it with postman, everything works as expected. Where I ran into my problem is when I'm sending the put data from React in the frontend.

I have a form, and I save my data in the local state, and then dispatch it to actions like this:

```
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const id = this.props.event.id
    const updatedEvent = {
      name: this.state.name,
      description: this.state.description,
      picture: this.state.picture,
      startDate: this.state.startDate,
      endDate: this.state.endDate,
      userId: this.props.userId
    }

    this.props.updateEvent(updatedEvent, id)
  }
```

Any value that is left empty in the form is overwriting my fields with nothing (an empty string). How do I properly handle this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You should mention that you are using Sequelize in your question. Inattentive people would just assume that you are using MongoDB otherwise.

Comment: Woops, my bad ! Thanks for mentioning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to filter your object, such that you remove any properties which have empty values and therefore won't be included in the database update.

In your `router.put()`:

```
router.put('/event/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = req.params
  try {
    const event = await Event.findByPk(id);

    // filter req.body to remove empty values
    const { body } = req;
    const filteredBody = Object.keys(body).reduce((resultObj, key) => {
      if(body[key] != ''){
        resultObj[key] = body[key];
      }
      return resultObj;
    }, {});

    const updatedEvent = await event.update(filteredBody);
    res.send(updatedEvent)
  } catch (error) {
    next(error)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I don't know why, but I thought PUT is gonna automatically do this for me. Thank you one more time :)